# Javascript: How Do I Refresh Page At Midnight?

Tags: javascript, clock

I have been trying to get my page to refresh at midnight, but the code I wrote is not working.

This is the code that I have written:

```
function reloadClock() {
  var reloadTime = new Date();
  var hrs = reloadTime.getHours();
  var min = reloadTime.getMinutes();
  var sec = reloadTime.getSeconds();
  
  // I tried this code, it will not work.
  if (hrs == 0 && min == 0 && sec == 0) {
    alert('this page will now reload');
    location.reload();
  }
  
  // I also tried this code, still can't get it to work.
  if (hrs == 14) { // Works as intended.
    alert(hrs);
    if (min == 31) { // Works as intended.
      alert(min);
      if (sec == 0) { // Does not work as intended.
        alert(sec);
        location.reload();
      }
    }
  }
  setTimeout(reloadClock(), 1000);
}
```

Does anyone know a solution for this?

Comment: `setTimeout(reloadClock(), 1000);` won't work either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check this

```js
const timerefresh = setInterval(function(){
  const time_ = new Date().toLocaleString('en-GB'); // return 24 hour time format in string, explaination about en-GB you can search on wikipedia, thats bored (:
  let date = time_.split(', ')[0].split('/'); // split the time strings to get date in array [day, month, year]
  let clock = time_.split(', ')[1].split(':'); // split the time strings to get clock in array [hour, min, sec]
  countDownTime(Number(clock[0]),Number(clock[1]),Number(clock[2]));
  document.getElementById('time1').innerHTML = 'date:'+date+', clock:'+clock;
  
},1000);
function countDownTime(h,m,s){
// some match to reverse the clock
document.getElementById('time2').innerHTML = 'countdown to midnight : '+ (23-h)+':'+(59-m)+':'+(60-s);
if(h === 23 && m === 59 && s === 59){ itsMidnight(); } // call its midnight 1 sec before clock 00:00:00
}
function itsMidnight(){
// its midnight, your function here
  console.log('midnight! reload.')
  window.location.reload();
}

// code below just for testing, you can delete it
let sectomidnight = 50;
function gotoMidnight(){
  clearInterval(timerefresh);
  setInterval(function(){
    sectomidnight += 1;
    countDownTime(23,59,sectomidnight);
  },1000);
  
}
```

```html
<div id="time1"></div>
<div id="time2"></div>
<button onclick="gotoMidnight();">goto 10 sec before midnight</button>
```

Comment: hei, i just do a revision at my code. check the last update

Comment: `check this` is not a helpful description. You should explain what you have changed and why. What was the problem with the original code? What did you change and why is that important? In the current form, the answer is a spot the difference.

Comment: it's very simple code, I assume you can understand it. which part do you not understand?

Comment: I understand the code. That's not the problem. But someone having the same problem as the OP or maybe even the OP, might not know what part of the original code was the problem, otherwise, the question would not have been asked in the first place. Answer should not only help the person how asked but any future reader.

Comment: i already added some comment at my code. hope its helpful